# Hide simple product on product list page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, filter, visibility

I have simple products and configurable products on my M2 and i would like to hide child of configurable on product list page but still getting them on the filters part.

If i set 'Not visible individually', i can get them if i go to the configurable product page, but they are remove from the filters, i tried 'catalog' and 'search' visibility but still not conclusive

Is it achievable by a native way or i need to do some customization ?
I have 'Improved configurable products' extension by firebear but i don't think i can achieve that with it.

Thanks for help

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no built in way to achieve this in Magento 2.

One solution is to create your own product list template and use logic in a custom module to filter the product collection to determine whether simple products are children of configurable products. You can then show or hide them as you require.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if i remove them form product collection, are they still in filters ? thanks

Comment: Yes - if you only override the product category list template, not the product search template.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that